# What is the difference between Collection.add() method and Collection.addAll() method in Collections in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have two `ArrayList`s (`a1` and `a2`) as below:

```
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
a1.add(8);
a1.add("a1");

ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList();
a2.add(a1); //output : [[8, a1]]
a2.addAll(a1); //output : [[8, a1], 8, a1]
```

My Questions:

1. Why does `a2.addAll()` method prints the data twice?
2. What is the exact difference between `add` and `addAll`? Both the methods return boolean.

Comment: Don't use *raw* generic classes. Always specify the generic type, e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Did you bother to **read the documentation** of the [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) *(appends the specified element)* and [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) *(appends all of the elements in the specified collection)* methods?

Comment: @Andreas - yes, I read the documentation but was confused looking at the output. thnx anyways

Comment: What's confusing about your `a2` list containing a list (`[8, a1]`) and two values (`8` and `a1`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why `a2.addAll()` method prints the data twice?

Because the first copy is already there after you called `add(a1)` on the previous line.

> What is the exact difference between `add()` and `addAll()`? Both the methods return `boolean`.

`add` adds a single item, while `addAll` adds each item from the collection one by one. In the end, both methods return `true` if the collection has been modified. In case of `ArrayList` this is trivial, because the collection is always modified, but other collections, such as `Set`, may return `false` if items being added are already there.

**Note:** Part of the confusion is that your lists are untyped, so they contain a mixture of objects: `a1` mixes strings and numbers, while `a2` mixes strings, numbers, and lists. Using a specific generic type for your collection would prevent this confusion by letting you do either `add` or `addAll`, but not both:

```
List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
a1.add("8");
a1.add("a1");
List<List<String>> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
a2.add(a1);
a2.addAll(a1); // <<== Does not compile
List<String> a3 = new ArrayList<>();
a3.add(a1);    // <<== Does not compile
a3.addAll(a1);
```

Answer (score 6):

The method `add()` adds one item to your `ArrayList`, in this case another `ArrayList`.
The method `addAll()` adds all items from one `ArrayList` to another.

To illustrate:

```
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
a1.add(8);
a1.add("a1String"); // I changed the string value to be more clear what is a1 and what is the string "a1"
// a1 content: [8, "a1String"]

ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList();
a2.add(a1);
// a2 content: [[8, "a1String"]] - basically [a1]
// a2 has one item - a1

ArrayList a3 = new ArrayList();
a3.addAll(a1);
// a3 content: [8, "a1String"] - same content as a1
// a3 has all the items from a1
```

Answer (score 0):

`add()` just adds the object to the next index:

```
public boolean add(E arg0) {
    this.ensureCapacityInternal(this.size + 1);
    this.elementData[this.size++] = arg0;
    return true;
}
```

`addAll()` copies the values to the given `Collection`:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> arg0) {
        Object[] arg1 = arg0.toArray();
        int arg2 = arg1.length;
        this.ensureCapacityInternal(this.size + arg2);
        System.arraycopy(arg1, 0, this.elementData, this.size, arg2);
        this.size += arg2;
        return arg2 != 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`add` is used when you need to add single element into collection.
 `addAll` is used when you want to add all elements from source collection to your collection.

In this particular case you're using `ArrayList` without specifying a generic argument, so `ArrayList<Object>` is assumed. When you're adding `a1` using `add` it will treat `a1` as a single object.

By default, `ArrayList` will be printed in square brackets, so you see `[[8, a1]]`. After that you're using `addAll` so, you just copy all elements from `a1`, and the result is expected again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

package others;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Practise {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//difference between add and addall 

    List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);
    arrList.add(5);
    arrList.add(10);
    System.out.println("printing arrayLIst 1");

    for(Integer printNumber: arrList) {
        System.out.println(printNumber);
    }

    List<Integer> arr2List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr2List.add(2);
    arr2List.add(4);
    System.out.println("printing arrayLIst 2");

    for(Integer printNumber:arr2List) {
        System.out.println(printNumber);
    }

    arrList.addAll(arr2List);
    System.out.println("printing updated arrayLIst 1");

    for(Integer printNumber: arrList) {
        System.out.println(printNumber);
    }   
}
```

}

## output

printing arrayLIst 1

5
10

printing arrayLIst 2

2
4

printing updated arrayLIst 1

5
10
2
4